# list of type parameter in trait scala

Tags: scala

```
trait myTrait[T]{
  def myList[T] =ListBuffer.empty
  def add(ele:T)= myList::ele
  def get:T=myList
}
```

I want to create a list and add elements inside the list and get to return the list

I am getting compile error.

**Update**

any alternative to use list instead of list buffer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're shadowing the trait level `T` in `myList`. Remove the type parameter from the method:

```
def myList = ListBuffer.empty[T]
```

Comment: how to define the return type of get

Comment: @coder25 Get is fine as it doesn't introduce a new type parameter, it uses the trait level `T`

Comment: can i use list instead of list buffer

Comment: how to do it with list it is immutable